# Cannot translate with statickidz api google translate-php

Tags: php, translation, google-translate

I can not translate with statickidz/php-google-translate-free
That is my code:

```
<?php

    require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
    use \Statickidz\GoogleTranslate;

    $source = 'fr';
    $target = 'en';
    $text = 'Bonjour';

    $trans = new GoogleTranslate();
    $result = $trans->translateGhost($source, $target, $text);

    echo $result;

?>
```

The problem I got is: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Statickidz\GoogleTranslate::translateGhost() in C:\xampp\htdocs\licenceactivation\test\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\licenceactivation\test\index.php on line 11`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you installed the lasted version (1.1.1). The method is called `translate` (see the [docs](https://github.com/statickidz/php-google-translate-free/tree/1.1.1))

Answer (score -2):

translate($source, $target, $text);

    echo $result;

?>